# Translating C to Obj-C file reading code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binary

I have this file which I need to read the first bytes to check the information.
I don't need to load the whole file, only the beginning..
The code in C is, more or less, what follows. It is a big code, so I just wrote the basic functionality here.

Now I want to make it 100% Objective-C, but I cannot find a way to do it properly.

```
FILE *f;
char *buf;

f = fopen ("/Users/foo/Desktop/theFile.fil", "rb");

if(f) {
fseek(f , 0 , SEEK_END);
size = ftell(f);
rewind (f);
buf = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*size);
switch( ntohl(*(uint32 *)buf) ) {
    case 0x28BA61CE:
    case 0x28BA4E50:
        NSLog(@"Message");
    break;
}

fclose(f);
free (buf);
```

The most close I got to this is what follows:

```
NSData *test = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

This gets me all the binary, but anyway, I got stuck. Better try to start all over..

Any help appreciated!

Comment: why don't use built-in way? `+[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile]` for example?

Comment: Your code looks wrong to begin with. You're `malloc`'ing a buffer the entire size of the file... and then inspecting that buffer without even reading anything. And you don't need a buffer that large if your stated goal is to just read the beginning of the file.

Comment: @KevinBallard this is only a temporary solution. My goal is to use Obj-C, so I thought I could put the effort into memory and buffer details when I come to it, rather than making the best code in C just to replace it.. Anyway, it is only to give an idea of how I want to compare the values inside the switch statement. I have already a list of hex values I wish to use.

Comment: @GiancarloMariot: I don't mean it's not "the best code", I mean *you aren't reading the file*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I sorted that out.. And did what follows.

Cheers and thanks for the help!

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"/Users/foo/Desktop/theFile.fil"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);

NSNumber *size = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedLong:len/2^20];

NSLog(@"%@", size);

switch( ntohl(*(uint32 *)byteData) ) {
    case 0x28BA61CE:
    case 0x28BA4E50:
        NSLog(@"Message");
    break;
}
[size release];
[filePath release];
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, valid C code is valid Objective-C code. So this is already in Objective-C.

What's your actual goal? What are you trying to do with the file? Is there a reason you can't use `NSData`?

Comment: I want to identify the data inside the files. The first 8 bytes in hex are parts of a list I already have. But, for starters, the hex becomes inverted when I try the Obj-C approach.
Second, I wish not to store all file on memory.
I just wish to use Objective-C to keep my project homogeneous and well documented. Could be in C, my if it is possible to be implemented, I rather prefer Obj-C.

Comment: @GiancarloMariot: No, “the hex becomes inverted” when you try the pure C code, because that code includes a function call (to `ntohl`) to byte-swap those first four bytes. The hex does not “become inverted” with the Cocoa one-liner, because there is nothing in it to do such a swap. As I said in my answer, you can use the exact same `switch`, including the byte-swap, after the Cocoa reading code.

Answer (score 1):

C code is already Obj-C. It's perfectly reasonable to just use what you're already doing. But if you're dead-set on using Obj-C objects to perform this, you want to take a look at [NSInputStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

> The most close I got to this is what follows:
>
> ```
> NSData *test = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
> ```
>
> This gets me all the binary, but anyway, I got stuck.

It's not clear where you're stuck, because that's the (simplest) correct way to read a file in one big slurp in Cocoa. You've successfully read the file; there's nothing more to do for that.

If you're looking to proceed to the `switch` statement, the pointer to the bytes that it read is `[test bytes]`. That's the pointer that you will want to assign to `buf`. See [the NSData documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/).

Comment: I am stuck because I can't make the same data in the switch statement using Objective-C. I don't know how to load only a part of the file into memory, I don't know what is the best way to perform it and I never find any examples of file partial byte reading anywhere.. I think the apple documentation is too subjective and lacks practical examples..

Comment: @GiancarloMariot: Well, you didn't ask about reading only part of the file into memory. The pure-C code in your question reads the whole file just as the Cocoa one-liner does. You should ask a new question about the partial-file goal.

Comment: @PeterHosey: Nitpick: his C code actually doesn't read the file *at all*. It just finds the size of the file, allocates a buffer of that size, and then inspects the garbage memory that he just allocated.

Comment: @KevinBallard: True; I'd forgotten that (I'd previously upvoted your comment on the question). *If it worked*, the C code would do the same as the Cocoa code. As they are, the Cocoa code is more correct.